# ShinyApp Google Login

Tags: r, google-authentication, shiny-server, shiny

I have a shinyapp and I want to enable certain features to the members who login to the app using google login.  I am not able to implement the Google login and authentication process within my app using the GoogleAuthR package.  Does anyone has an example of a sample ShinyApp which allows the audience to login through either google or any other social forum authorizations

Appreciate a demo with code.

PS:  I have no intention of running statistics on Google data but I only want to do away with the hassle of creating a login module for my app and let Google login take care of the hassles

Thank you
SD

Comment: Take a look here? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleAuthR/vignettes/googleAuthR.html

Comment: I am relatively new to this world so please excuse my ignorance.  Based on the document below: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#enable_the_google_api. , I tried to create my customer ID and secret.  My app is in shinyapps.io so I entered under Authorized JavaScript origins field the following URI https://dmarket/shinyapps.io (my app link is https://dmarket.shinyapps.io/Main so wasnt sure what to enter). Now to test the login, can I test it locally in RStudio or do I deploy the code from your document access_token <- callModule(googleAuth, "loginButton") directly in the shinyapps.io

Comment: You can test it locally it you add the port and the localhost to the Google project screen (e.g. 127.0.0.1:1221) -  check out the setup steps in the readme https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/googleAuthR#google-api-setup

Comment: Also if you are using it just for ID purposes, check out https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/googleID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem in a different manner using gar_shiny_ui

1. we need to define the UI in the server
2. Get user info and extract email from his/her google login
3. Use this email to determine if the person is from your organisation
4. If the person is from your organisation, show the main UI else show a UI which says 'You cannot access this tool'

   ```
   #Function to get google user data which will be used for checking if the user comes from your organisation
   user_info <- function(){
   f <-                         gar_api_generator("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo",
                        "GET",
                        data_parse_function = function(x) x)
   f()}

   #UI code based on Output coming via server code
   ui<-uiOutput('myUI')

   #Server side code to do all the lifting
   server = function(input, output,session) {
   gar_shiny_auth(session)

   #Check if user has already logged in with google authentication
   gmail='john.doe@unkwown.com'  
   tryCatch({
     x<- user_info()
     gmail=x$email
     print(gmail)}) 
   print(gmail)

   #Create a different UI based on where the user comes from (MyOrg or Not)
   output$myUI <- renderUI({

     if(grepl('@myorganisation.com',gmail)){
       ui = fluidPage(
         shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
         title='Your Product',
         theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
         img(src = "mycompany_logo.png", height = 200, width = 400),

         sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel(write whatever you want)
           ,
           mainPanel( write whatever you want)
         )
       )} 
     else {
       ui = fluidPage(mainPanel(
         h4("My Company Data Team Presents", allign="center"),
         h1("My Tool", allign="center"),
         p("Tool that makes analysing any and everything ",
           em("incredibly easy "),
           "with a simple click."),
         br(),
         p("- But unfortunately, your account does not have the rights to ",
           em("access "),
           "this tool.")))  }
   })
   shinyApp(gar_shiny_ui(ui, login_ui = silent_auth), server)
   ```

Answer (score 4):

There is an example in the [readme](https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/googleAuthR), that you can see working as a [Shiny app here](https://mark.shinyapps.io/googleAuthRexample/)

If you are intending it for just logging in purposes, check out [GoogleID](https://github.com/MarkEdmondson1234/googleID) package which is built with `googleAuthR` with this in mind.

Example code below:

```
## in global.R
library(googleAuthR)
library(shiny)

options(googleAuthR.scopes.selected = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener")
options(googleAnalyticsR.webapp.client_id = "YOUR_PROJECT_KEY")
options(googleAnalyticsR.webapp.client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET")

shorten_url <- function(url){

  body = list(
    longUrl = url
  )

  f <- gar_api_generator("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url",
                         "POST",
                         data_parse_function = function(x) x$id)

  f(the_body = body)

}

## server.R
source("global.R")

server <- function(input, output, session){

  ## Create access token and render login button
  access_token <- callModule(googleAuth, "loginButton")

  short_url_output <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    ## wrap existing function with_shiny
    ## pass the reactive token in shiny_access_token
    ## pass other named arguments
    with_shiny(f = shorten_url, 
               shiny_access_token = access_token(),
               url=input$url)

  })

  output$short_url <- renderText({

    short_url_output()

  })
}

## ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
  googleAuthUI("loginButton"),
  textInput("url", "Enter URL"),
  actionButton("submit", "Shorten URL"),
  textOutput("short_url")
)


### If the above global.R, server.R and ui.R files are in folder "test" like so:
## /home
##    |->/test/
##            /global.R
##            /ui.R
##            /server.R
##
## Port 1221 has been set in your Google Project options as the port to listen to
## as explained in authentication setup section
## run below in /home directory
shiny::runApp("./test/", launch.browser=T, port=1221)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Has anyone implemented a facebook login as well in shinyApp?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, although it's not a big change to the code as they both use OAuth2.

Comment: I will try to see if I can leverage the work done in GoogAuth and build on it.  The challenge may be with respect to the callback URL