# shiny app + Google Auth + roles

Tags: r, shiny, google-authentication

I have a shiny app to which I  as per [restrict access using GoogleAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306169/shinyapp-google-login). I'm now wondering whether there's any way I can attach roles to the Google accounts according to which I could differentiate access to certain features of the app. [Some parts of the Google Apps API Docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/roles) sound like something like that should be possible in principle but I have no idea how to make this work in practice.