# R Shiny - User Management

Tags: r, nginx, shiny, shiny-server

I have developed an R Shiny web application that is currently hosted on an AWS EC2 instance (using the Shiny Server free version). I am looking for a free (open source) way to allow user management. For instance, I need to have an admin login and a general user login option. Whenever a new user visits the app, he should be able to register by providing his details and the admin will receive the request to approve new user registration request.

What option(s) do I have to accomplish this in a less complex way?

*PS:* I am not just looking for user authentication (which I know can be done using nginx), but I am primarily looking for ways to enable user registration and admin approval features into my shiny web app. Relevant links to tutorials/working examples will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can try google and facebook logins:
1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306169/shinyapp-google-login
2) https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/fb-login
3) AOTH0 https://auth0.com/blog/adding-authentication-to-shiny-server/

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way to do it is to set up a small database that contains usernames and passwords. Then when the user enters her credentials you can cross check them against that database.

The parts in the app that differentiate between users can be implemented with `renderUI` and `uiOutput`.

You can see an example of that kind of implementation here:
https://github.com/yanirmor/shiny-user-management
https://yanirmor.shinyapps.io/shiny-user-management/